# Setting X axis start to first value in first series, Chart control

Tags: c#, winforms, charts

I have a chart control on a windows form and recently changed the data I'm adding for the x axis from a string representing the date to a datetime type.

before changing I set the minimum X axis to 1 one so that the line starts at the Y axis now I'm using a date I can't do the same!

Is there a simple way to always start a line on a chart control at the Y axis?

Here is what I was doing and what I'm now trying:

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = 1;
```

And was adding data to the chart thus:

```
seriesAve.Points.AddXY(strDate, average); //StrDate is a string, average is a double.
```

I now do it this way:

```
seriesAve.Points.AddXY(dt.Date, average);
DateTime tpdate = dateTimePicker1.Value;

// results in cannot convert datetime to double. 
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = tpdate.Date;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All X- and Y-Values in a `Chart` are stored as `doubles`.

When adding a Value as as `DateTime` it gets converted to double implicitly with the [`ToOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tooadate%28v=vs.110%29.aspx) conversion function.

So when you need to set a value like the `Minimum`, `Maximum` etc you need to call this function in your code:

```
chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum = tpdate.Date.ToOADate();
```

To convert it back to a `DateTime` use the [`DateTime.FromOADate`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.fromoadate(v=vs.110).aspx) function:

```
 DateTime tpdate = DateTime.FromOADate( chart2.ChartAreas[0].AxisX.Minimum);
```

Comment: Thank you @TaW  I had been going around in circles with this, it has fixed my issue, much appreciated...