# C# WinForm Chart Label and Grid Setting

Tags: c#, charts, real-time

I want to fix the labels in the Time section of the real-time Temperature and Humidity information graph I developed in C#. I want the graphic to be a constantly changing structure with 7 or 8 grids, as shown in the 2nd figure, but I couldn't figure it out. I would be happy if you help. Thanks.[image]
When I add a point to the chart, it starts randomly like this. My minimum and maximum values are constant for 15 minutes. After 15 minutes, the graph works as my maximum value is datetime.now and its minimum value is datetime.now - 15 minutes.

[image]

I edited this image with photoshop. This is how I want it to be, with the start time right at the origin and the end time at the end of the last label. There are 7 intervals visible in the image. I'm thinking of using 8.

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/38633233/14171304 - https://stackoverflow.com/a/30681437/14171304 - In case you mean the margins, see: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15048193/14171304

Comment: The first link is similar to the answer to my question, but I did not see anything different from my code. I couldn't find a solution. The 2nd and 3rd links have nothing to do with my situation.